# SwiftUI - Picker doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a little problem,

I have a Swift app with a picker:

```
/// DATA.swift

import SwiftUI

class FormPage: ObservableObject { 
    @State var country = ["USA", "Japan", "Germany"]
    @State var index = 0
}

/// FORM.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var choiceForm = FormForFormulaire()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $choiceForm.index, label: Text("Pays de destination")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< choice.country.count) {
                        Text(choiceForm.country[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The picker view is working but it doesn't update: I click Japan, and the view doesn't change.

Sorry for my English, I hope someone understood me!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Published` for index inside the `FormPage` class

```
@Published var index = 0
```